# Jacobian of a Robot

Tags: jacobian

What is the dimension of the Jacobian of a robot with 9 actuators and 6 degrees of
freedom? 6 x 9 is my guess but not sure. Can someone please explain ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, 6x9.   Since $$\dot{x} = J \dot{\theta}$$ each column of the Jacobian represents the differential change in one of the six $x$ coordinates with respect to each of the joints.